# If there are narrative contradictions in the 5 books of Moses, why is it so?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment

There are many narrative contradictions in the 5 books of Moses. Does this prove the Torah is manmade or is there a deeper layer?Rabbi Ishmael said the Torah was written in the language of men etc.
Example:
After the men are defeated at Hormah, do they turn back into the wilderness OR do they return to Kadesh? (Deut 1:40, 2:1 ; Num 14:25  vs Deut 1:46 ; Num 20:14).

There is a clear contradiction here. There are many such contradictions in the Torah.

Why is this so? Have Jewish commentaters dealt with these narrative contradictions?

Comment: Yes the contradictions are dealt with. You want a resolution for all of them? That's too broad for one question. You're satisfied with just the one you mention?

Comment: Two recent excellent books list and resolve many of these contradictions: [To this very day](https://korenpub.co.il/products/to-this-very-day-fundamental-questions-in-bible-study?_pos=1&_sid=0f86a14bd&_ss=r) and [Ani Maamin](https://korenpub.co.il/products/ani-maamin-biblical-criticism-historical-truth-and-the-thirteen-principles-of-faith?_pos=1&_sid=9ccc76f2a&_ss=r)

Answer (score 2):

First off, yes, apparent contradictions are dealt extensively by Jewish commentators, but the question is too broad to be answered in a single post.

Secondly, in many cases, things which may seem to one reader to be a clear contradiction is not a contradiction at all to another reader. To address the one contradiction that you mentioned, here is an answer.

Secular Biblical scholars have noticed many contradictions and their answer is that different passages were written by different human authors. Thus, you have J (who uses YKVK as God's name), E (who uses Elokim as God's name), P (the Priestly Author), R (a redactor), and D (the Deuteronomist). So the easy thing for them to have answered is that this single passage was authored by different authors.

You can look at this website, [Tanach.us](https://tanach.us/), to see color coding of purported authorship of Biblical passages according to the Documentary Hypothesis. And you will see that they say that Deut 1:40 and 1:46 are both written by Dtr1, not Dtr2, Dtn, E, or Other. Similarly, they have Numbers 14:25 and Numbers 20:14, which are farther apart, both written by J.

So it would seem that the secular Biblical scholars do not consider this clear contradiction to be a real contradiction.

Two possible answers, just off the cuff. First, in both Deuteronomy and Numbers, the command from God, to turn to the wilderness by way of the Reed Sea, rather than fight, comes before the battle. In both cases, the description of where they went, to Kadesh, comes after the unsuccessful battle. Maybe where they were to go changed after their defeat?

Second, how do you know that Kadesh is not "in the wilderness"? I had always assumed that it is indeed part of the wilderness. [Numbers 33](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0433.htm) lays out the stages of their encampments of the wilderness, and one of those stages is Kadesh:

> 36 And they journeyed from Ezion-geber, and pitched in the wilderness of Zin--the same is Kadesh.

So **Kadesh is a wilderness** - namely, the wilderness of Tzin. So it would only be a "clear contradiction" if you know the specifics of wildernesses and the Biblical geography to such an extent that it is somehow certain that the wilderness by way of the Reed Sea (Suph) is a different wilderness than the wilderness of Tzin (that is, Kadesh). Can you show this? Since scholars say that Kadesh is part of the Aravah, and since Deuteronomy 1:1 says "in the wilderness, in the Arabah, over against Suph," aren't these quite possibly the same place?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the same event is described *from multiple angles*, to give us a better picture; hence the Creation is described first from a big-picture perspective (humans come in male and female, like all the other animals), and then in a more human one (a lonely man).

If a commandment appears different in different places, the Talmud will harmonize those and explain how each apply. (E.g. how many days of eating matzah -- six or seven?)

As for narratives that appear to differ, most notably Deuteronomy's retelling of earlier episodes in the desert -- the more traditional commentaries tend to harmonize them.

For example: Moses claims that Se'ir allowed them to pass through, but previously it says Edom refused.

- While the two nations are usually synonymous, it's possible that there were sub-tribes here: e.g. "The U.S. refused the refugees, but California took them in."
- It's possible to read Moses' statement as "as *our offer stood* with Se'ir", even if they didn't take it.
- Even if the *narrator* is reliable, that doesn't mean the *characters* are: It's even possible Moses, in asking the Emorites for passage, is being "creative" or "ambiguous" as to what previous nations had done.

Contemporary scholars of a traditional bent, such as [Joshua Berman](https://korenpub.co.il/products/ani-maamin-biblical-criticism-historical-truth-and-the-thirteen-principles-of-faith?_pos=1&_sid=9ccc76f2a&_ss=r), are open to a broader possibility. Deuteronomy clearly links back to previous books, so it's very hard to argue that it was two different texts woven together. Rather, *the version as retold by Moses* in Deuteronomy (remember what we said about narration? The vast majority of Deuteronomy is Moses talking) may have color commentary that differs from the original.

- Berman points out that covenants at the time usually started off with a re-telling of relevant history, often "creatively re-described" in terms that would best support the agreement at-hand. He feels that's the best way to explain some of the history in Deuteronomy -- how it best leads up to the Israelite's agreement with God pre-entry. Obviously, read his book for more!
- Rabbi Angel's review of Berman's book (in *Tradition*) takes a slightly different approach, that it is Moses consciously modifying the story to drive home some points in his sermon.

Comment: yes moses does contradict some events in the torah and has retold the events differently.